# Are there any realtime voice activity detection (VAD) implementations available?

Tags: audio, signal-detection, reference-implementation

I'm looking for a realtime [VAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) implementation like Discord/Mumble/Teamspeak have.

My goal is to have a system that let's me use the same VAD for all my VoIP applications, as well as something I can use to facilitate VAD for push to talk only applications.

Mumble is open source though I wasn't able to find what I needed when I had a look.

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad, looks like the Python bindinds as well as the C code are MIT-licensed.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is not an answer in the quality I'd like it to be, but the Mumble VAD is in [`AudioInput.c`](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blob/master/src/mumble/AudioInput.cpp#L759) , as a quick browsing yielded:

```
speex_preprocess_ctl(sppPreprocess, SPEEX_PREPROCESS_GET_PROB, &prob);
fSpeechProb = static_cast<float>(prob) / 100.0f;

// clean microphone level: peak of filtered signal attenuated by AGC gain
dPeakCleanMic = qMax(dPeakSignal - gainValue, -96.0f);
float level = (g.s.vsVAD == Settings::SignalToNoise) ? fSpeechProb : (1.0f + dPeakCleanMic / 96.0f);

bool bIsSpeech = false;

if (level > g.s.fVADmax)
    bIsSpeech = true;
```

What's done here is that Speex, a FOSS voice codec and utility pack is used to get an estimate for the silence->voice transition. Whyever, Mumble converts that probability value (probabilities: $\in[0,1]$) to a percentage, and then compares it to the internal setting.

So the algorithm of interest here is definitely not within Mumble, but [libspeexdsp](https://github.com/xiph/speexdsp/tree/master/libspeexdsp)!

Funnily, that's basically where it goes down in speexdsp's `preprocess.dsp`

```
/* FIXME: This VAD is a kludge */
st->speech_prob = Pframe;
if (st->vad_enabled)
{
    if (st->speech_prob > st->speech_prob_start || (st->was_speech && st->speech_prob > st->speech_prob_continue))
    {
        st->was_speech=1;
        return 1;
    } else
    {
        st->was_speech=0;
        return 0;
    }
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

So, this really just boils down to an SNR estimate of the current audio frame:

```
/* Speech probability of presence for the entire frame is based on the average filterbank a priori SNR */
Zframe = 0;
for (i=N;i<N+M;i++)
    Zframe = ADD32(Zframe, EXTEND32(st->zeta[i]));
Pframe = QCONST16(.1f,15)+MULT16_16_Q15(QCONST16(.899f,15),qcurve(DIV32_16(Zframe,st->nbands)));
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this working. Had trouble getting speexdsp installed on windows so I set up a VM with a linux distro. How do I read in audio from the microphone to pass to the speexdsp library?

Comment: https://speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node13.html

Comment: I've seen that, but I still can't work out how to pass my microphone as an input. I was hoping that would just be as simple as say /dev/mic/, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I might be getting somewhere with PortAudio. I've got a data stream from my microphone, though I'm not confident it is the format speexdsp will need. I'll report back with more info if I work it out.

Comment: How does this fare on discriminating speech from music?

Comment: I don't know! But since that would really just be a matter of using the speex vad function on a lot of random samples of music and you might have easy access to such: go and try out!